# Dictionary entry legend

Tags: dictionary

I'm reading the section on sanseido.net about how entries from a certain dictionary are laid out but I'm having a little trouble understanding the section below. As far as I can tell, ▼ is put on the right of non-Jouyou kanji (as in the first example). I can't quite figure out what ▽ or 《　》 are used for. What is「常用漢字表」の「付表」?

> (2) 常用漢字とその音訓を表示した。
>
> 【　】の中の漢字が「常用漢字表」にないものには「 ▼ 」、その漢字が「常用漢字表」にはあるが見出しに相当する音訓が示されていないものには「 ▽ 」を漢字の右肩に付した。また、「常用漢字表」の「付表」の語は 《　》で囲んで示した。
>
> う ごう　 －がふ　[0] 【 烏▼合 】
> お たけび　を－　[2][0] 【 雄叫▽び 】
> かわせ　かはせ　[0] 【《為替》】
> さ なえ　 －なへ　[0] 【《早苗》】

Also, unrelated to the main question, but does anyone know what the [2][0] is referring to? I was thinking something to do with pitch accent but why are there two numbers? Two different possible pitches?

Comment: 「烏」なんか常用外なのかぁ～???

Comment: @istrasci 鳥{とり} is on the 常用漢字表, but 烏{からす} (note the missing stroke) is not.  It's a 人名用漢字, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

▼ is for kanji that don't appear *at all* on the [常用漢字表](http://www.bunka.go.jp/bunkashingikai/soukai/pdf/kaitei_kanji_toushin.pdf).

▽ is when the kanji appears on the chart, but the word uses a reading the chart does not include.  Their example of `雄叫び` marks `叫` this way because the official chart only includes the readings キョウ and さけぶ for that kanji.

The 付表 referred to is part of the 常用漢字表 as well (see page 154 of the PDF linked above).  It contains readings such as 当て字 and 熟字訓 which are assigned to entire compounds rather than individual kanji.  For example, the reading かわせ is assigned to the entire compound 為替.  These are marked with 《》 in 大辞林.

Yes, [2][0] refers to two possible accent locations. (second mora and unaccented).

Comment: Here is a chart explaining the pitch accent types by the same publisher: http://www.sanseido.net/main/Dictionary/Hanrei/meikoku_accent.aspx#ACC-002